# Typescript type inference, from sibling attribute, in factory/driver pattern

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to describe an array of drivers in configuration and have the configuration type be inferred from the generic type defined on the Factory.

eg.

```
const drivers: FactoryDefinition[] = [
  {
    id: 'foo1',
    // FooFactory is type Type<Factory<FooServiceConfig>>
    factory: FooFactory,
    // no type safety here, config type is any, should be FooServiceConfig
    config: {
      apiKey: 'xxx',
    },
  },
];
```

Given the generic types used by all drivers:

```
/**
 * Driver/Factory pattern interfaces
 */

export interface Service {
  do(): void;
}

export interface Factory<TConfig, TService> {
  make(config: TConfig): TService;
}

// utility type 
export interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

An implementation of those generic types:

```
/**
 * Driver Example
 */

export interface FooServiceConfig {
  apiKey: string;
}

export class FooService implements Service {
  constructor(private config: FooServiceConfig) {}
  do() {
    // some api call using config.apiKey
  }
}

export class FooFactory implements Factory<FooServiceConfig, FooService> {
  make(config: FooServiceConfig): FooService {
    return new FooService(config);
  }
}
```

And then be able to describe multiple drivers:

```
export interface FactoryDefinition<TConfig = any> {
  id: string;
  factory: Type<Factory<TConfig, Service>>;
  // this is where I would like to infer the type from factory
  config: TConfig;
}

const definitions: FactoryDefinition[] = [
  {
    id: 'foo1',
    factory: FooFactory,
    // no type safety here, config type is any, should be FooServiceConfig
    config: {
      apiKey: 'xxx',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 'foo2',
    factory: FooFactory,
    // no type safety here, config type is any, should be FooServiceConfig
    config: {
      apiKey: 'yyy',
    },
  },
];
```

Tried the following:

```
export interface FactoryDefinition<TFactory = any> {
  id: string;
  factory: Type<TFactory>;
  config: TFactory extends Factory<infer C, any> ? C : any;
}

export interface FactoryDefinition<
  TFactoryType extends Type<Factory<any, Service>> = Type<
    Factory<any, Service>
  >,
> {
  id: string;
  factory: TFactoryType;
  config: TFactoryType extends Type<Factory<infer C, any>> ? C : any;
}
```

Using Typescript version ^4.9.5

Comment: TS doesn't have direct inference on type params of generic types; it does have inference for generic *function* calls, though, so you can write helper functions [like this](https://tsplay.dev/N5kgdW) to give you the inference you're looking for.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is a valid solution. You can provide this as a possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a direct way to do this. There was a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#30120](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30120) to allow the compiler infer a generic type argument in a generic type.  This was marked as a duplicate of [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), a suggestion to support "partial type argument inference".  This would allow developers to skip some generic type arguments and have the compiler infer them.  As you have seen, [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) do *not* solve this: they let you omit type parameters (`<TConfig = any>`), but the compiler does not *infer* anything when you do that; it just uses the default value for the missing argument.

If microsoft/TypeScript#26242 is ever implemented, you might be able to write something like this:

```
// ⚠ NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT, DO NOT USE ⚠
const driver: FactoryDefinition<infer> = {
  id: 'foo1',
  factory: FooFactory,
  config: {
    apiKey: 'xxx',
  },
};
```

But this is not possible right now.  Until and unless this feature is implemented, we need to find another way.

---

The usual workaround is to use a generic helper function, because calling a generic function is one of the situations where the compiler will actually infer type arguments for you:

```
const factoryDefinition = <T,>(fd: FactoryDefinition<T>) => fd;

const driver = factoryDefinition({
  id: 'foo1',
  factory: FooFactory,
  config: { apiKey: 'xxx' },
});

// const driver: FactoryDefinition<FooServiceConfig>
```

This is not much different from the desired `FactoryDefinition<infer>`.  You get the type you wanted without repeating yourself, at the cost of a function call.

You can also do this for arrays, by writing the helper function in terms of a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
const factoryDefinitions = <T extends any[]>(
  ...fd: { [I in keyof T]: FactoryDefinition<T[I]> }
) => fd;

const definitions = factoryDefinitions(
  {
    id: 'foo1',
    factory: FooFactory,
    config: { apiKey: 'xxx' },
  },
  {
    id: 'foo2',
    factory: FooFactory,
    config: { apiKey: 'yyy' },
  },
);

/* const definitions: [
     FactoryDefinition<FooServiceConfig>, 
     FactoryDefinition<FooServiceConfig>
] */
```

Also looks good.

---

Note that depending on how the inference algorithm matches things, you may see types like `FactoryDefinition<{apiKey: string}>` instead of `FactoryDefinition<FooServiceConfig>`; these are essentially the same, but if you want to see the other type you can play around with the *priority* of the inference sites, so that `config` is not used to infer `T`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for a lengthy discussion about inference sites and their priorities.  For example, [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) indicates you can intersect with an empty object type to lower the priority:

```
interface FactoryDefinition<T> {
  id: string;
  factory: Type<Factory<T, Service>>;
  config: T & {}; // essentially the same as T,
                  // but has lower inference priority
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#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-FvJAAGSyQyHUlQ2uW3P5xhFiatNsBZQsBTMiekPMFmcluwBTnNIJLgwI5xjhTndAtcdUkjr6eFZzKN0VyAAchYnwAjM+PPI69ZAy2SG-ElvS5VVQXBTRn26aDn25b9DFUAwhVHfBFDPeAVyvG9CzvEsnXSf03ACPgUMvK1sM3QY5zsSAej6AY2g6XYF3kJYFiXTQZEgLYAEkGHoSISEIFhvB2TDyKnHDi3sXidiCYxd33fQSOPVCFEkyiL1-NcNNwjhlHkN0pifV8Py-UMyL-eNCAAoCpiVf5ey4sD1Ug6Dulgww7K8wyLJMt9CAAJnM+zLNIf9V0Aiye048VXJfEhEs87zv0Q44HJPXTi3WbiAIo3DmwTYM2UcgJHUi-LpPwn5CICHZoBePggA)